# Relink back-end mdb from front-end Access form using VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

My Access database is split into back and front-end. 
I have created an Access form in the front-end that contains a textBox, a *Browser* button and a *Relink* button.

When I click *Browse*, file manager pops up to choose my .mdb file. After the file is choosen, the path to the file is displayed into the textBox.

What I want is when I press *Relink* button, it should take the path from textBox and link my back-end file to my front end.

Here is my code so far:

```
'browse button
 Private Sub browseBtn_Click()
   Dim objDialog As Object
   set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
   With objDialog
        .show
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            'textFiled displays the path
             Me.textField = .SelectedItems(1) 
        End If
    End With
 End Sub

'relink button
Private Sub linkBtn_Click()
    Dim newConnection As String
    Dim currentPath As String
    currentPath = Me.textField
    Dim tblDef As TableDef
        tblDef.Connect = newConnection
        tblDef.RefreshLink
End Sub
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: sorry, i've edited it

Comment: Why isn't the back-end already linked in front-end? Usually, a user should not have to regularly search and connect the data source. Also, your last question is something you should tell us. What does code currently do? Undesired results? Error?

Comment: Need to loop through TableDefs collection. Review https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/08/03/automatically-relink-microsoft-access-tables/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure it out in the end, here is the full code:

```
Private Sub browseBtn_Click()
Dim objDialog As Object

 Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)

 With objDialog
   .title = "Please select the backend file"
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
    Me.textField = .SelectedItems(1)
   End If
 End With
End Sub

Private Sub linkBtn_Click()
  RefreshLinks (Me.textField)
End Sub


Public Function RefreshLinks(strFilename As String)
   Dim dbs As dao.Database
   Dim tdf As TableDef

   Set dbs = CurrentDb

    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
         If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
             tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strFilename
             Err = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            tdf.refreshlink
             If Err <> 0 Then
                RefreshLinks = False
                 Exit Function
             End If
         End If
    Next tdf
    RefreshLinks = True

End Function
```